# pass PHP variable to javascript value

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to display my PHP variable to JavaScript value
Here is my PHP and javascript code.

```
<?php 
$text = "Rates are subject to change without prior notice";
?>
<script>
    $('#typewriter').typewriter({
        prefix : "*** ",
        text : ["Rates are subject to change without prior notice"],
        typeDelay : 50,
        waitingTime : 1500,
        blinkSpeed : 200
    });
</script>
```

inside the text parameter i want to pass my PHP variable.

Comment: use `text :<?php echo $text; ?>,`

Comment: text value using array is it working for this method?

Comment: Yes, it should work.

Comment: This question **Asked a million times here**

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php 
$text = "Rates are subject to change without prior notice";
?>
<script>
    $('#typewriter').typewriter({
        prefix : "*** ",
        text : [<?php echo $text; ?>],
        typeDelay : 50,
        waitingTime : 1500,
        blinkSpeed : 200
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wont work as the quotes are missing for the text.

Answer (score -3):

You can do it by using the following code

```
     <script>
          $('#typewriter').typewriter({
          prefix : "*** ",
          text : ["<?php echo $text;?>"],
          typeDelay : 50,
          waitingTime : 1500,
          blinkSpeed : 200
        });
     </script>
```